# Code Converter Circuit

Tags: digital-logic

Make a BCD to Excess-3 Code Converter by using a binary to decimal encoder and 4 OR gates.
I know how to make a binary to decimal encoder, but how do I proceed from there?

Comment: By using a truth table or K-map.

Comment: After the binary to decimal encoder, what K-Map will I get? I'm confused...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: BCD to Excess 3]

Write down your 10 inputs, D0 to D9 and the Excess03 code (4 outputs).

Table will have 10 lines.  You will have 4 inputs (BCD) feeding 4 outputs.

The key here is the 4 OR gates can have as many inputs as required.  Look at the 1's in output and can you see how to get outputs from inputs.